# Perceptron Learning - Update Weights

Tags: perceptron

I am studying Perceptron Learning, and have a question which sort of leaves a bit confused. As I am self-teaching, I have looked through a variety of papers, tutorials, powerpoints etc., and at times it seems they use different algorithms to adjust the weights of the network.

For example, some include a learning rate, others include individual weight/input product while others just the sum of all weight/input products.

So, am I right in assuming that there are multiple algorithms which all lead to the same final weight matrix/vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not the same.

You are right that there are many algorithms, but they may lead to different weights. Its like sorting algorithms - there are many, each of them does the same thing, but some are stable and some are not, some use additional memory, and some sorts in place.

Comment: So, to sum up, would they all still lead to valid weights though that correctly classify my input? Ie, would the network have multiple solutions for the weight vector?

Comment: Yup, that is the thing. You perceptron may be better or worse in classifying input, depending on how good you learning algorithm is, but they all lead to same effect.

Comment: Ok, so pretty much the only thing that changes is the amount of iterations needed in the training stage? Or do you mean that all algorithms will lead to correctly classifying the test, but some will lead to better results "in the wild"?

Comment: No algorithm can ensure proper learning of perceptron, because perceptron is used to approximate output. The same learning data passed in different order may lead to different weights in the end, so it will approximate wanted output with different precision. Different learning algorithms approximate output with different quality and usually they are better than others for different kinds of approximated function.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article: An Intuitive Example of Artificial Neural Network (Perceptron) Detecting Vehicles and Pedestrians from the Camera of a Self-driven Car. I have tried to explain with simplest possible examples.

You can check, I hope that can help you to understand the weight updating in Perceptron. Here is the link.

[https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10](http://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10)

I also explained Learning Rate with examples.

[[[image: Example of Detecting Vehicle and Pedestrian]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk77B.jpg)](http://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10)